# How can I assign type 'double?' to a double?

Tags: flutter, dart, types, config

I'm trying to write a config file and I have the following code:

```dart
const config = const Config();

class Config {
  final Map<String, double> blur;

  const Config({this.blur: const {'sigmaX': 50.0, 'sigmaY': 50.0}});
}
```

And I'm trying to use `config.blur['sigmaX']` in another file for the use of `ImageFilter` like this:

```dart
filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: config.blur['sigmaX'], sigmaY: 50),
```

But I get the following error when I trying to build and run it:

```
The argument type 'double?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'double'.
```

Null Safety is on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a value that might be null, and the `blur` operator can't take a null value for the `sigmaX` parameter.  You can use the `??` (null coalescing) operator to provide a default value for the case where `config.blur['sigmaX']` happens to be null:

```
filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: config.blur['sigmaX'] ?? 50, sigmaY: 50),
```